# Typed subsets of enums

Tags: java

Let's say I have the following `enum` type:

```
public enum Country {
    CHINA,
    JAPAN,
    FRANCE,
    // ... and all other countries
    AUSTRIA,
    POLAND;
}
```

Now I would to create a subset of this enum, conceptually like:

```
public enum EuropeanUnion constraints Country {
    FRANCE,
    // ... and all other countries within the European Union
    AUSTRIA,
    POLAND;
}

public enum LandlockedCountries constraints Country {
    // ... all landlocked countries
    AUSTRIA;
}
```

I'd like to create subsets of an `enum` type so that I can write methods such as

```
Set<Person> getNationalMembersOfEuropeanParliament(EuropeanUnion euCountry);
```

Using the subtype `EuropeanUnion` for parameter `euCountry` protects the API user from accidentally passing in an invalid country, e.g. the non-EU `JAPAN`.

Are there any ways of "constraining" the range of valid enum values so that one can benefit from the static type system?

Comment: You have to start with the subset as a base enum and then inherit from it and add to it in a derived enum.

Comment: Short answer: no, Java's type system won't let you do this.

Comment: Since this is not allowe, an alternative would be to use flags on the Country enum like isEU, isLandLocked.

Comment: If one country cannot be in many subsets you could theoretically make `Country` an interface and extend it with multiple enums.. And then declare all of them as constants. But practically the answer is no.

Comment: Java's enums won't allow you to do this - plain old objects would be just fine, not all of your compile time constants need to be inside of enums.

Comment: Do you know of any established workarounds to my challenge? I could think of a solution by moving from `enum Country` to a quite boilerplatey `class Country`, but maybe someone already came up with a practical solution.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to consider using an `EnumSet`; this won't give you new types, but it lets you work with collections of enum values in a set-theoretic way:

```
public enum Country {
    CHINA,
    JAPAN,
    ...;

    public static final EnumSet<Country> EUROPEAN_UNION = EnumSet.of(Country.FRANCE, Country.AUSTRIA, ...);
}
```

`EnumSet` implements `Set`, so you can use e.g. `addAll()`, `removeAll()` and `retainAll()` to produce unions, differences, and intersections (just remember to copy the left-hand-side set first).

Comment: Could wrap the constant with `Collections.unmodifiableSet` to make it immutable.

Comment: Thank you for the `EnumSet` suggestion. But I think it cannot help me in situations where I'd like to have a "typed subset API", e.g.  `getNationalMembersOfEuropeanParliament(EuropeanUnion euCountry)`

Comment: @Abdull: Indeed, it won't; this solution is not type safe.

Comment: @Bubletan: Good idea; that is much safer.

Answer (score 4):

`enum` is just syntactic sugar for a class with a private constructor whose only instances are stored in `public static final` fields. By defining this manually instead, you can gain additional flexibility, such as the ability to create subclasses and implement interfaces. So here's one possible solution, but it requires one class per country, so think carefully before you decide to do this:

```
public interface Country {
    static final France FRANCE = France.INSTANCE;
    static final Norway NORWAY = Norway.INSTANCE;
    static final Sweden SWEDEN = Sweden.INSTANCE;
    static final Denmark DENMARK = Denmark.INSTANCE;
    ...
}

public interface EuropeanUnionCountry extends Country {
    static final France FRANCE = France.INSTANCE;
    static final Sweden SWEDEN = Sweden.INSTANCE;
    static final Denmark DENMARK = Denmark.INSTANCE;
    ...
}

public interface ScandinavianCountry extends Country {
    static final Norway NORWAY = Norway.INSTANCE;
    static final Sweden SWEDEN = Sweden.INSTANCE;
    static final Denmark DENMARK = Denmark.INSTANCE;
}

// In case you need to store information about each country
public class CountryBase implements Country {
    protected CountryBase() { }
}

public class France extends CountryBase implements EuropeanUnionCountry {
    public static final France INSTANCE = new France();
    private France() { }
}

public class Norway extends CountryBase implements ScandinavianCountry {
    public static final Norway INSTANCE = new Norway();
    private Norway() { }
}

public class Sweden extends CountryBase
        implements ScandinavianCountry, EuropeanUnionCountry {
    public static final Sweden INSTANCE = new Sweden();
    private Sweden() { }
}

public class Denmark extends CountryBase
        implements ScandinavianCountry, EuropeanUnionCountry {
    public static final Denmark INSTANCE = new Denmark();
    private Denmark() { }
}
```

The advantage of this solution is that you now have complete type safety: `Country.NORWAY` can be passed to a method that takes `Country` or `ScandinavianCountry`, but not to one that takes `EuropeanUnionCountry`. 
Also, `Country.NORWAY == ScandinavianCountry.NORWAY`. Note that it would have been enough to list all the countries in `Country`, but repeating the appropriate ones in the subinterfaces might make it easier to keep track of which belong to which category.

You can do this using only classes as well, but then you're limited to a tree-based hierarchy, thus precluding e.g. having both European Union and Scandinavia (since they only partly overlap).

Comment: ScandinavianCountry.FRANCE :)

Comment: @bayou.io: In our dreams ;)

Comment: @bayou.io Good observation; it's probably better to define the sets separately. It should produce a warning, though, and you can't pass it to a method that takes `ScandinavianCountry`.

Comment: IMHO better would be `public interface ScandinavianCountry{ static final **ScandinavianCountry** NORWAY = Norway.INSTANCE;` - that verifies if the entry actually implements given marker. Also, `public enum Norway implements Country, ScandinavianCountry { INSTANCE;}` is much shorter (at the cost of solid base class)

Answer (score 0):

Well, so we can define two independent enum types

```
enum Country{ 
    GREECE
    ...

enum EU{
    GREECE  
    ...
```

The question is how to link `EU.GREECE` to `Country.GREECE`. We don't need the link at compile time; we are satisfied if at runtime we can convert 
`EU.GREECE` to `Country.GREECE`

```
    private EU()
    {
        this.country = Country.valueOf(this.name());
    }
```

This is not totally type safe, but at least it fails fast at runtime - if any name in EU is not in Country, we'll get an error early on when EU class is initialized.

Now, to further justify this design, we can argue that EU.GREECE should not be the same object as Country.GREECE anyway, because EU.GREECE may contain more metadata and actions that are specific to EU.