# typescript how to omit enum values

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got enum

```
enum Status {
  Cancelled = 'cancelled',
  Completed = 'completed',
  Created = 'created'
}
```

and I want to create another enum only with Completed and Created value

```
enum StatusMinimal {
  Completed = 'completed',
  Created = 'created'
}
```

I tried to use Omit but it works only with types. Is it even possible to do it in typescript?

Comment: I would just ditch enums and use type unions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a property/parameter based on the `Status` and `Exclude` the unwanted values

```
function test(s: Exclude<Status, Status.Cancelled>): void {}


test(Status.Completed)
test(Status.Created)
test(Status.Cancelled) // not assignable
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=21#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gKClAwgkAY2ABsTgATKAXigHJCDizK6AabPAewgAdy4lGvUI9+wQRXadcAJ2BIhtBvMVTMAX0zaAZmCJwAllxBRBKOAAoUALigBRAB6ESYCsAA88JKjaxEyCgAdPhEpOQUAHwAlHYAblyGVOha2uZW3oEhYgKU0ZjplpmoIUzheQXAFkUBJXIKktFAA)

Comment: I'd use that or `s: Status.Completed | Status.Created`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no trivial way.
See this [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193529/typed-subsets-of-enums).

I would start with Minimal and extend the Status enum from the minimal implementation. (I know, not what your asked for)

Answer (score -3):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850720/typescript-how-can-omit-some-items-from-an-enum-in-typescript).
You can basically use the builtin TypeScript utility type [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion).

Or you could do it like this :

```js
enum StatusMinimal {
  Completed = 'completed',
  Created = 'created'
}

enum StatusExtended {
  Completed = 'completed',
  Created = 'created'
}

type Status = StatusMinimal | StatusExtended;
```

Comment: I don't want type, just new enum

Comment: @quippe I don't think it's possible with just enum :/